# Appsscript UI libraries to develop gmail addon

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, gmail, add-on, gmail-addons

I have been using *Card Service* to work on *Gmail addon*, using *appsscript*. I also tried using html, but it didn't work well. Are there any **libraries related to UI in appsscript for Gmail addons**?

Answer (score 1):

The Card Service is the only Class you can use to show a html in a Gmail Add-on [1]. You can start and guide yourself from the Gmail Add-on quickstart [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/quickstart/

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service.html